# Export a makefile from codeblocks

Tags: c++, makefile, codeblocks

Is it possible to export a makefile from a C++ codeblocks project?

If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 10):

I use cbp2mak, read up on it here http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=9731.msg69835#msg69835

Answer (score 7):

You may also use this one http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,13675.0.html

The project is cbp2make and it is hosted here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cbp2make